# API Platform : add element to relation without overwriting existing ones

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I try to add an element to a collection without overwriting existing ones, in a PATCH method. For now, the element is correctly added but existing elements are deleted. Any ideas ?

The first entity (Office) :

```
....

/**
 * @var Service[]
 *
 * @Groups({Office::LIST, Office::DETAIL})
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Service", mappedBy="offices", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $services;

....

/**
 * @param Service $service
 */
public function addService(Service $service): void
{
    if (!$this->services->contains($service)) {
        $this->services[] = $service;
        $service->addOffice($this);
    }
}
```

The second entity (Service) :

```
....

/**
 * @var Office|null
 *
 * @Groups({Service::LIST, Service::DETAIL})
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Office", inversedBy="services")
 */
private $offices;

....

/**
 * @param Office $office
 */
public function addOffice(Office $office): void
{
    if (!$this->offices->contains($office)) {
        $this->offices[] = $office;
    }
}
```

The body of my patch request on the office resource :

```
{
    "services": [
        "/api/services/9"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the full request string with curl? What content-type used?

Comment: Why don't you make a post request on the other side of the relationship? It's generally what I do. Makes more sense to me.

Comment: @EugeneRuban here is the curl request, content type is application/json : `curl --location --request PUT 'http://127.0.0.1/api/offices/21' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{"services": ["/api/services/12"]}'`

@yivi The problem will be the same as a service have a collection of office, it's a ManyToMany

Comment: Maybe it's not possible and I just have to re-send all elements in the collection ?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible yet, but can be done with the custom controller for it. Check this issue https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1628

Answer (score 1):

It is not flexible to do like this, the more logical should be to resend all the collection needed.

Anyway, if you want something like this, I suggest to use a Listener (pre-update?), to get the correct and add the new one.
But don't forget you cannot remove element after this... so you have to be sure :D